# How I do I add a panel in between two panels in Java?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm trying to create a comment section akin to that of Reddit, in which when a user presses the comment icon, a panel containing a textbox and buttons will appear. How do I make sure the comment panel appears in between its parent comment and the following comment?

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue or what you're trying to achieve inlcude ascii art or an image along with what would happen if you resized the window, would components be bigger or should they stay the same but add extra space around them?

Comment: `JPanel#add(Component, Int)` and/or `JPanel#add(Component, Object, Int)` depending on how the original container is laid out

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/